# spThin* package: A column return the same value in all the lines

Tags: r, statistics

I have a table which have these features:

```
> head(ocorrencias)
  month year      y       x
1    10 1962  49.25 -123.14
2     4 1959  49.25 -123.14
3     8 2019  24.76 -107.47
4    10 2015   5.15  -54.34
5    12 2021 -23.57  -46.73
6     8 2018  38.98  -77.40
> dim(ocorrencias)
[1] 9513    4
```

I want to use the function *thin* to reduce the number of points I'm using. y and x are coordinates.

Here is the code:

```
ocorrencias$species <- paste(ocorrencias$month, ocorrencias$year, sep = "_")
```

Here a col called species was created:

```
head(ocorrencias)
  month year      y       x species
1    10 1962  49.25 -123.14 10_1962
2     4 1959  49.25 -123.14  4_1959
3     8 2019  24.76 -107.47  8_2019
4    10 2015   5.15  -54.34 10_2015
5    12 2021 -23.57  -46.73 12_2021
6     8 2018  38.98  -77.40  8_2018

library(spThin)
library(ggplot2)

points<-ocorrencias[,3:5]

points_thinned <- thin(loc.data = points, 
                       lat.col = "y", long.col = "x", 
                       spec.col = "species", 
                       thin.par = 50, reps = 10, 
                       locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, 
                       write.files = TRUE, 
                       max.files = 5, 
                       out.dir = getwd(), out.base = "points_thinned", 
                       write.log.file = T,
                       log.file = "points_thinned.txt" )

sp <-(points_thinned)
wm <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50", xlim = c(-80, -30), ylim = c(-60, 10))
ggplot()+ coord_fixed()+ wm +
  geom_point(data = sp[[1]], aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),
             colour = "black", size = 1)
getwd()

occ1<-read.csv("D:/.../points_thinned_thin1.csv", sep = ",")
head(occ1)
dim(occ1)

head(occ1)
  species       x     y
1 10_1962 -123.14 49.25
2 10_1962  -54.34  5.15
3 10_1962   55.42 25.35
4 10_1962  -76.23  3.26
5 10_1962  -76.98  2.13
6 10_1962  -76.33  1.11
> dim(occ1)
[1] 631   3
```

The main problem is that in occ1, col species, all the lines are the same. At the beginning those lines were all different and I need them to continue being different. I'd be glad to receive any tips/suggestions to solve this problem.